# POSTGRES_USER not taken into account

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy postgres as a `StatefulSet` on `k3d`.

I set the environment variable `POSTGRES_USER`, but when I try to connect to the db, it isn't taken into account and I see that authentication has failed. I can login with the password `pgpassword` and default user `postgres`.

Why isn't the `POSTGRES_USER` taken into account?

This is my yml:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgresql-db
spec:
  serviceName: postgresql-db-service
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresql-db
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresql-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgresql-db
          image: postgres:latest
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgresql-db-disk
              mountPath: /data
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: pguser
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: pgpassword
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /data/pgdata
      volumes:
        - name: postgresql-db-disk
          hostPath:
            # directory location on host
            path: /opt/x/projects/tilt_test/data/
            # this field is optional
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Comment: Those environment variable just tell the system what to set up for the initial name and password when creating the db.  The client also needs to know what to use when connecting, and that is set up separately.  Those are called PGUSER and PGPASSWORD

Answer (score 3):

> but when i try to connect to the db, it isn't taken into account, and i see that authentication has failed.

It works exactly as it should. The `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` system variables are used to create the default user and password when creating the database. **If, on the other hand, you intend to log in to an existing user later, you must set and use system variables: `PGUSER` and `PGPASSWORD`.** [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-envars.html) is the explanation:

> - `PGUSER`  behaves the same as the  [user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-USER)  connection parameter.
> - `PGPASSWORD`  behaves the same as the  [password](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-PASSWORD)  connection parameter. Use of this environment variable is not recommended for security reasons, as some operating systems allow non-root users to see process environment variables via  ps; instead consider using a password file (see  [Section 33.15](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-pgpass.html)).

You can also find a complete tutorial [How to Deploy PostgreSQL Statefulset in Kubernetes With High Availability](https://devopscube.com/deploy-postgresql-statefulset/). Additionally, you will find an explanation for `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` system variables:

> POSTGRES_USER: The user that should be created automatically when the Postgres process starts.
> POSTGRES_PASSWORD: The password for the user created by default.

In this case, logging into the database takes place during readiness and liveness probes.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I haven't actually come back to it yet, i'll have a look tonight and accept the answer accordingly.  As a comment, the docs on dockerhub for POSTGRES_USER don't seem particularly explicit on the fact that the user isn't available after db creation: "POSTGRES_USER: This optional environment variable is used in conjunction with POSTGRES_PASSWORD to set a user and its password."